# WebGL - Multiple Objects

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, cube, three.js

I am new to WebGL.

What I am trying to do is setup multiple cubes in a straight line, and when I use the keyboard I want to be able to move left and right to select a cube. Every time I move left and right, I want the next cube to the left or right to become bigger, and pan the camera over.

Is there any way of doing this? I can only find tutorials telling me how to work with one object.

Thank you!

Comment: Show me your code for one cube and I will tell you what to change to support multiple cubes

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is:

1. Hold a numeric variable say "selected_cube = 0"
2. If press left "selected_cube++"
3. If press right "selected_cube--"
4. camera_pos = camera_pos + (cubes[selected_cube].target - camera_pos) * time_delta * speed
5. on draw: if drawing selected_cube: use bigger size else: use normal size